# Primefaces tabView insert in content a jsf page on dropdown select

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am newbie in Primefaces, and I want to ask any ideas how can I show a new page in a `tabview` content? For example I have write this code

```
<p:tabView orientation="left" dynamic="true" cache="false" prependId="false" 
            style="height: 100%" id="mainTabView"  
            activeIndex="#{navigationController.model.mainTabSelectedIndex}">

            <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{navigationController.onMainTabChange}" onstart="KTI.Globals.onMainTabChangeStart()" oncomplete="KTI.Globals.onMainTabChangeComplete()"/>

            <p:tab title="#{msg['tabs.title.playlist']}" id="tabPlaylists">
                <ui:include src="/sections/playlists/list.xhtml"/>
            </p:tab>
            <p:tab title="#{msg['tabs.title.workstations']}">
                <ui:include src="/sections/workstations/list.xhtml"/>
            </p:tab>
</tabView>
```

And I want to add a new page with include in the content by selecting a value from a dropdown from the header. Should I think to make a `<p:tab>` which is hidden(I did not found any solution for this) or I can append my page to the content somehow on selected value?

Comment: What issue you are facing? In `<p:tab/>` you can include the page.

Comment: I have a tabView with tabs, and in header a dropdown witch contains a logout and a settings, and when I click on settings it should appear the settings page in the tab content. I can`t make it with p:tab because in the menu it should not appear a settings tab

Comment: I would try to hide the settings tab with `rendered` attribute for the `p:tab`. If you need dynamic number of tabs, use `value` and `var` attributes of `p:tabView`.

Comment: If I use render than when I click on settings then it will show the tab and that`s not how I want. It should show just the page without the tab.

Comment: If you dont want to show tab name or Tab then why you are using Tab?

Comment: It was just and idea if I could do it like this. But I can use whatever I want, I just need to show my jsf page in the tabView content on selecting a dropdown value from header

Comment: Ok. Use `ui:include` with a condition to show the tab page or show the settings like: `<ui:include src="#{myBean.showSettings ? '/path/settings.xhtml' : '/path/tabs.xhtml'}" />`. Or determine the `src` content completely in the backing bean like: `<ui:include src="#{myBean.getMainView()}" />`. But if I understood this correctly your answer has nothing to do with `p:tabView`.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me but like this also I need to use a <p:tab> and my problem is cause it should not display the <p:tab> in the "menu" just the content should display witch should be displayed buy selecting a settings value from header dropdown. Sorry for my English probably because of it is the misunderstanding.

Comment: Why the settings have to be in the tab but shouldn't displayed as tab? Sounds strange....anyway... try to hide the tab title with css?

Comment: Didn`t need to be in tab, just else I dont know how to append my jsf page to tabView content. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to include pages dynamically inside existing tabs or add dynamically new tabs including pages, you have to be aware that `ui:include` works at view build time while primefaces component tags works at view render time. Therefore you need to work at build time as well. It is very important to know that your datamodel won't probably have been properly loaded the first you access a page messing up with build time operations (later on how to properly initialize your bean) unless your are aware of these caveats

The following example covers the fixed tab show/hide use case and dynamic tabs as well:

```
<p:tabView id="tabView">
            <p:tab title="Static 1" rendered="#{page.renderTab1}" >
                <ui:include src="tab1.xhtml"></ui:include>
            </p:tab>
            <p:tab title="Static 2" rendered="#{page.renderTab2}" >  
                <ui:include src="tab2.xhtml" />
            </p:tab> 
            <c:forEach var="includedTab" items="#{page.dynamicTabs}" varStatus="loop">
                <p:tab title="#{includedTab.title}">
                    <p:fragment id="tabContentWrapper">
                        <ui:include src="{includedTab.xhtmlPath}"></ui:include>
                    </p:fragment>
                </p:tab>
            </c:forEach>
            <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{page.onTabChanged}"></p:ajax>
        </p:tabView>
```

where `#{page.dynamicTabs}` is a List of objects like these

```
public class IncludedTab {

  private String title;     // the title of your tab
  private String xhtmlPath; // somepath/page.xhtml

  public IncludedTab(String title, String xhtmlPath) {
    this.title = title;
    this.xhtmlPath = xhtmlPath;
  }

  public String getTitle() {
    return title;
  }

  public String getXhtmlPath() {
    return xhtmlPath;
  }

}
```

and your backing bean would be similar to this

```
public class Page {

private List<IncludedTab> dynamicTabs;

public Page(){
    //you can prepare your tabs here
}

/*
 * since <ui:include> works at view build time
 * your chances to prepare your data are
 * 1 - your bean construction or
 * 2 - the first time jsf tries to get the data by calling #{page.dynamicTabs}
 */
public List<IncludedTab> getDynamicTabs(){
    //or here
    if(dynamicTabs==null){

        dynamicTabs = new ArrayList<Page.IncludedTab>();

        ...add your stuff here...
        dynamicTabs.add(new IncludedTab("yourTitle", "yourpath/yourpage.xhtml"));
    }
    return dynamicTabs;
}
}
```

A very important note is that you also need to ajax update the full `p:tabView` to make the new tabs visible. In case you need to update via ajax the content of a single tab (an optimization to avoid refreshing the whole tabView, depends on your usecase) you cannot update `p:tab` directly because it breaks Primefaces javascript. In my example `tabContentWrapper` is included to be used in this way.